# IIS 7 Resource cannot be found MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi everyone I'm trying to publish my site via ISS7. I have deployed all necessary dll files but I get "Resource cannot be found". Could you help me please

```
Server Error in '/WebCity' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /WebCity/Views/Home/Index.cshtml


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Comment: are you using the built in web dev server of Visual Studio or you have deployed the application on localhost i.e iis ?

Answer (score 0):

A .cshtml file should never be requested as a URL.

Instead, request a route that maps to a controller action (presumably the one that renders the .cshtml view you are attempting to locate), e.g.

> /WebCity/Home/Index

Comment: @FurkanSönmez: I did show an example.  If you are requesting a relative URL it would probably be (depending on your routing configuration) `/WebCity/Home/Index`.  If you are requesting a fully qualified URL (e.g. if you are making an Ajax callback from JavaScript) it would be `http://mydomain.com/WebCity/Home/Index`

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the `Global.ascx` file you will see the default routes setup like

```
  routes.MapRoute(
              "default",
              "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new { action = "Index", id = "" }
             )}
            );
```

therefore the requested URL in your case would look like

> ```
> /Home/Index
>          ^ Controller Action
>  ^ Controller
> ```

if your application is deployed at localhost then it would probably look like

```
http://localhost/Home
```

or

```
http://localhost/Home/Index
```