# How to publish MVC3 project on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I want to ask how to publish a MVC3 project on IIS 7

I have done  these steps:

```
Installed neccessary dlls

Microsoft.Web.Infastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Changed Framework
```

But it still does not publish

Comment: The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Comment: you dont have to include the `.cshtml` in the requested route it should be like `/localhost/Home` or `/localhost/Home.Index`

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 7 Resource cannot be found MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086379/iis-7-resource-cannot-be-found-mvc3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Your requested URL is wrong. You cannot directly access Views. You should pass through a controller action, so the correct url that you need to type in your browser is `/home/index`.

You may take a look at some of the tutorials about ASP.NET MVC here: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Allright but where I have to change request URL in Global asax ?                     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: You don't have to change anything. The default routes make it so that if you request `/` in the browser, the Index action of Home controller will be executed. You type the url in your browser address bar.

Comment: I get another error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed on the server?

Comment: And how do you expect this to work without installing it? You want to do bin deployment? Make sure that all necessary assemblies are present in the bin folder for this: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: Yeap I dont wanna install mvc3 plug in on server I have install all necessary assemblies but still I get error

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy it you can keep your projet in root folder where local disk C: or whatever and please dont forget to which framework you are using and you can change the framework at application pool